# My navigation not working using bootstrap-4.0.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I just started to learn bootstrap but I don't know where I'm going wrong with the code here.This is the navigation bar code [taken from here](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)
I've used `bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist.zip` version.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>first boot</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>        
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>     
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home <span 

class="badge">42</span></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages <span 

class="badge">3</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[My result is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9ZeU.png)

Comment: To help you, we need to know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What error are you getting, what is the desired and the obtained result

Comment: I've copied your code into a Fiddle and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/w5oyhm5h/. You seem to have conflicting styles on your site.

Comment: The Fiddle has no JavaScript; the issue is not with any scripts.

Comment: @IshanMahajan see my answer.

Comment: Why am I getting so many downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Bootstrap Alpha 4.0.0 with class names from an earlier version of Bootstrap. The current recommended version seems to be 3.3.7. If you really want to use Bootstrap 4.0.0, read up on the [alpha documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/); it has slightly different class names.

Comment: Why is it so I'm using code snippet from their main website

Comment: Their main website assumes you're using version 3.